# How to use Python (3.81) with Anaconda in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3

I was working in Sublime Text 3 on an exercise from the Python Crash Course book that's dealing with parent classes and child classes, and I ran into an issue with the `super()` function when trying to build/run my program.

I'm using the Conda (Anaconda) build system to build my programs. I'm getting a traceback error with the `super()` function when I run my program with Conda:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/watchmen1/Desktop/python_work/Chapter 9/ice_cream_stand.py", line 61, in <module>
    braums = IceCreamStand('Braums')
  File "/Users/watchmen1/Desktop/python_work/Chapter 9/ice_cream_stand.py", line 52, in __init__
    super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python', '-u', '/Users/watchmen1/Desktop/python_work/Chapter 9/ice_cream_stand.py']]
[dir: /Users/watchmen1/Desktop/python_work/Chapter 9]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

However, I don't get this problem when I run it with just the regular Python 3 build system, and my understanding is that at least in Python 3, the `super()` function doesn't require an argument when using it to connect a parent and child class.

I had assumed that Anaconda was  running as Python 3 when I used it as the build system. However, since the error seems to be saying I need to input an argument, I'm wondering if it's actually running as Python 2.7 or something since my book notes that in python 2.7, the `super()` function does require arguments.

I can use Python 3 as the build system, but considering that I am planning on using Anaconda in the future, I was hoping I could figure out what's going on.

```
class Restaurant():
    """ An attempt to model a restaurant."""

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        """Initialize restaurant name and cuisine type."""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        """Simulate a sentance naming the restaurant and giving its cuisine type."""
        print(self.restaurant_name.title() + " is a restaurant that serves " + self.cuisine_type.title() + " food.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        """Simulate a sentance announcing the restaurant is open."""
        print(self.restaurant_name.title() + ", is now open!")

    def set_number_served(self, customers_served):
        """Set the number of people served at a #restaurant."""
        self.number_served = customers_served


    def increment_number_served(self, customers):
        """Add selected amount of customers to the total number served."""
        self.number_served += customers


# restaurant = Restaurant('Shake Shack', 'Americana')

#print(restaurant.resturant_name.title())
#print(restaurant.cuisine_type.title())

# restaurant.describe_resturant()
# #print("")
# restaurant.open_resturant()
# print("\nNumber Served: " + str(restaurant.number_served))
# print("")

# #restaurant.number_served = 20
# restaurant.set_number_served(20)
# print("Number Served: " + str(restaurant.number_served))

# print('')

# restaurant.increment_number_served(22)
# print("Number Served: " + str(restaurant.number_served))

class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
    """Create child class of restaurant that represents an Ice Cream Stand."""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type='ice_cream'):
        """Initialize attributes of the parent class."""
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
        self.flavors = []

    def show_flavors(self):
        """Display the list of flavors the Ice Cream Stand offers."""
        print("\nThis Ice Cream Stand offers the following flavors: ")
        for flavor in self.flavors:
            print("\t- " + flavor.title())

braums = IceCreamStand('Braums')
braums.flavors = ['Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'Sherbert']

braums.describe_restaurant()
braums.show_flavors()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: usually in full error message you can see path with Python's version was used to run code - so you should see which version whas used. As I remeber `super()` without argument is since 3.3+

Comment: BTW: using 3.8 also may not be good idea because it is very new version and it may have bugs and some modules may not be ready to work with 3.8

Comment: The error message shows that the build system that you're using is executing `python`; on a Mac that could be Python 2 and not Python 3. You mentioned that running this with a Python 3 build system works; is that a build system you set up yourself? The default Python build system that ships with Sublime executes `python` just like this, so that would make me think that this build (or rather the package you're using that provides it) is using `python` when it should perhaps be using `python3`. That may or may not be a configuration issue in the package, I'm not familiar with it myself.

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" except for the section talking about “Thanks for your attention” or “Thanks for your consideration” as those are considered fluff and will be edited out.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks, I'll check that out before I post again. As far as this problem, though, I think I'm just going to come back to it later when I've gotten better in my understanding of the fundamentals. I guess I just lack so much of the vocabulary that it's difficult for me even to articulate what I'm trying to do. Which means I probably just need to get a little further along to the point that I at least have a better grasp on what the problem even really is. Having said all that, thanks to everybody who commented, I'll at least be a better poster the next time around.